# How to add null or undefined check for PrimeNG TreeTable field?

Tags: angular5, primeng, primeng-treetable

**Question1**

Is it possible to add null/undefined check for field type ? As type may be null for some data ?

```
 <p-treeTable [value]="files">
    <p-column field="name" header="Name"></p-column>
    <p-column field="size" header="Size"></p-column>
    <p-column field="type" header="Type"></p-column>
 </p-treeTable>
```

Will some thing like below should work ? Is there any way ?

```
     <ng-template*ngIf="type; else empyType">
       <p-column field="type" header="Type"></p-column>
     </ng-template>

     <ng-template #empyType>
       <p-column field="" header="Type"></p-column>
     </ng-template>
```

**Question 2**

How to add scrollbar in case of treetable overflows ? I tried adding  CSS to ui-treetable-tablewrapper as overflow:scroll ?

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4813 this says Prime-Ng 6 is coming in April 18. which may have scroll-able treatable! waiting till then.

Comment: Why do you need to do that ? If `type` is null or empty for a given file, you won't have any data in *Type* column for the corresponding row...

Comment: Yes exactly ! it should show empty cell for that particular column in a row. But it is giving error as type is undefined

Comment: Can you please share the output of your data assigned to `files` array ?